# Javascript enter key fix

Tags: javascript

I made a code using javascript
 the code basically says:
 if enter is pressed
 take the user input from the input box
 and check if it is right.
(this is for a simple maths game)
I have a timer in place
and after the timer is done the game ends

the problem is when the user clicks play again
and uses the enter key
it presses it twice.

I don't know how to fix this problem

sample code is provided of the enter key function:

```
onEvent("addition", "click", function() { //This is what happens when the user picks the addition mode of the game.
newGame("plus", "minus", "times"); //This is just a function I made to restart the score and time for the game
timer(); //A function to start the timer

onEvent("game", "keydown", function(event) { //This is where the main problem is.
  if((event.key === "Enter") && (seconds < 0)) { //This makes it so it will only work when enter is the key pressed.
//When the user clicks play again the script works, but enter is clicked twice while the user only clicks the keyboard once.
  z = getText("text_input1"); //<This is all the mathy bits you don't need to worry about the parts under this line
  console.log(z);
  x = a + b;
  console.log(x);
  if(z == x){
   setText("result", "Correct");
   setText("text_input1", "");
   changeNum();
   score++;
   setText("scoreT", score);
  } 
  if(z != x) {
    setText("text_input1", "");
    setText("result", "Incorrect");
    changeNum();
    if(score > 0) {
    score--;
    setText("scoreT", score);
  }
  }
  }
});
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Sounds like you are adding the handler again when player starts a new game. We would need to see more code to understand how onHand is integrated with the rest of the code.

Comment: I added more of the script.

Answer (score 0):

every time the user click center key,you have to check the game is started

when the game started ,it should not be again start.

below is sample code

```
 let isStarted = false;
            function checkState(){
                if(isStarted === true){
                    return;
                }
                isStarted = true

                //todo something else
                //when the game is done , isStarted should be false
            }
```